# Firestore dynamic querying in Flutter Fire

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of contents, I want to retrieve them applying certain filters under certain circumstances.

I store filter values in a bloc object, this values can be null or not. If it's null, the filter should not apply, if it has a value, the filter applies.

I would like to do something like that:

```
  CollectionReference contents =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('content');

  if (_bloc.searchQuery != null && _bloc.searchQuery.isNotEmpty) {
    // Add where criteria here
  }

  if (_bloc.publishUntilQuery != null) {
    // Add where criteria here
  }

  if (_bloc.publishFromQuery != null) {
    // Add where criteria here
  }

  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: contents.snapshots(),
    builder:
        (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      // ...
    },
  );
```

The problem is that I don't know how to construct something like a Query object to later add it to the final search.

How to solve this issue? Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference-class.html), the [`CollectionReference`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference-class.html) class inherits from the [`Query`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query-class.html) class. In addition, the methods from the `Query` class used to refine the Query (e.g. `orderBy()`, `where()`, etc...) return a `Query`. You can therefore use these different methods to refine your initial Query, applying "certain filters under certain circumstances", as follows:

```
  Query contents =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('content');

  if (_bloc.searchQuery != null && _bloc.searchQuery.isNotEmpty) {
    contents = contents.where('....', isEqualTo: '....');  // For example, to be adapted
  }

  if (_bloc.publishUntilQuery != null) {
    contents = contents.where('....', isEqualTo: '....');  // For example, to be adapted
  }

  if (_bloc.publishFromQuery != null) {
    contents = contents.where('....', isEqualTo: '....');  // For example, to be adapted
  }

  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: contents.snapshots(),
    builder:
        (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      // ...
    },
  );
```